# How to Decrypt a PDF using PDFKit in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-pdfkit

I have a password protected PDF file and I need to Decrypt it using PDFKit or some other way, When I use unlock with password, it is unlocked but it is still encrypted could anyone help me with this code:

```
func handlePDF(url: URL, password: String) {                      
    print(pdfDocument.isEncrypted, pdfDocument.isLocked) // true, true
                            
    if let pdfDocument = PDFDocument(url: url) {
        if pdfDocument.isEncrypted {
            if pdfDocument.unlock(withPassword: password) {
                print(pdfDocument.isEncrypted, pdfDocument.isLocked) //true , false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: All I want is to Decrypt the PDF in the app I am developing.

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/read_operations) explains, your result is expected and correct:

> ```
>  isEncrypted: Bool { get }
> ```
>
> `true` if the document is encrypted, *whether it is locked or unlocked*; `false` otherwise.

(My italics.) So don't worry, be happy.

Comment: yes but when is pass the PDF data to the server it asks for password. so how can I get the Decrypted PDF data

Comment: My question is "How to Decrypt a PDF"

Comment: You have decrypted the _data_. That is all you need to do.

Comment: All I want is to make the "isEncrypted" to be false

Comment: You cannot do that. The file _is_ an encrypted file. If you want an unencrypted file, that would be a _different_ file. Do you see?

Comment: Yes that is what I need, I want an unencrypted file of the encrypted file

Comment: So go ahead and make that.

Comment: Think about it like this. Start with an encrypted PDF on your desktop. Try to open it. You can't until you give the password. You give the password. You can now read the PDF! OK, close the PDF. Now try to open it. You still can't until you give the password again! That's because the PDF is _still encrypted_. You can't change that. You can read it because you know the password, but you can't claim that an encrypted PDF is not encrypted; it _is_ encrypted.

Comment: I want to do that through my app, so any idea how could I convert encrypted file data to unencrypted file data?

Comment: Just write the data out as new file that isn't encrypted.

Comment: Again, think about how you would do this on the desktop. You'd open the encrypted PDF by giving the password. You'd select all the pages. You'd copy them. You'd create a new PDF document. You'd paste the pages into it. You'd save. Try it yourself!